# Dymola/Modelica & Matlab/Simulink export into Qt export - Can I use different compiler?

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, export, dymola

I have a Matlab/Simulink project representing a complex mechanical process and which includes exported Dymola parts. I wish to export this model into a Qt-made GUI to provide a user-oriented interface. The Qt project is then exported into a stand-alone application.

Regarding the integration of the Dymola/Simulink model in Qt, since the 1st and 2nd export were made using MSVC 2010, can I use MinGW to export the Qt project into the stand-alone application? Or is it mandatory to use the same compiler for all exports? If so, can I use other version of MSVC (I only have MSVC 2015 and MSVC 2017 on Qt)?

Software & compiler version:

- Dymola 2014 FD01 + Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
- Matlab 2013a + Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
- Qt 5.12.2 64bits + MinGW 7.3.0 64bits

Comment: Does exporting take forever? In case not: simply try your different scenarios and you'll see whether it works

Comment: Exporting takes a while yes, and I have constraints regarding software use, so I can't test solutions whenever I wish.

Comment: It depends on many factors that are not clear from the description: for DLLs it is normally possible to mix more freely. For non-DLL-code in  C you can in many cases link with a later version of MSVC (with some exceptions - in particular MSVC 2017 and later), but for C++-code using STL it does not work for different major versions.